# How to safely send highscores data to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend

I'm creating a simple browser game and want to save players score in DB after they lose. No authorization or something complex just user enters his nickName and sends `{nickname: string, score: number}` to the server. That's easy, but how I can be sure that `score` the client sends to the server is the exact same value, that player got during the game?
For example, potentially someone can use something like postman and send as many scores as he wants to the API endpoint and it will not be cool.

Comment: IMPOSSIBLE...... Most games will send moves back and the server handles it and figures out the score.

Comment: For future readers: [Possible duplicate of "Sending a client-side high-score to a server securely"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/148425/sending-a-client-side-high-score-to-a-server-securely)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally: **You can't**.

You have a couple of options to make it a little bit more difficult to cheat:

- obfuscate the sending of the data, add some complex math, some hashing, etc. to make it not as easy to submit a fake score. This obviously does not help against a motivated attacker / cheater.
- Submit the solution as well the score. E.g. if you have a puzzle game and count the time and moves until a puzzle is solved - then send an array of all moves to the server, that way the server can verify the solution and the score (to some extent)

  - optionally continously talk to the server to send the current progress + time to the server
- all this of course does not prevent the user from figuring out a solution and then "solving" the puzzle in an instant, but you cannot do anything about that anyway, other than implement some "fraud detection". That would consist of expecting some time between each step of the solution, if steps happen within a few microseconds it is unlikely you have human user, same if all steps are exactly 1.5s apart, etc.

Overall this is a **very** complicated and complex topic and there is no fully working solution. Every game can be cheated, through different attack vectors, e.g.:

- Chess (or other strategy games) can be beaten by having a computer next to you to compute and play moves for you

  - there is much fraud detection going on here, e.g. comparing the moves played with the ones another engine would play - if the overlap is too large you do not play against a human, if the opponent takes the same amount of time for all moves, even the most simple ones, chances are you are not dealing with a human either
- any FPS can have a wall hack / aimbot

  - much work is being done here, from both the game devs and the hacking community, a lot of code obfuscation, punkbuster and other anti cheat programs watching the client memory, taking screenshots, etc.

After googling myself (especically for something called "proof of work") I found [this security.stackexchange post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/148425/sending-a-client-side-high-score-to-a-server-securely) which has the same gist and proposes largely the same countermeasures.